# Ember js: TypeError this.init is undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

This is related to my [previous question](/questions/15580767/ember-js-in-my-example-why-does-the-logic-in-the-router-continue-even-though-th). The answer there seemed to solve the problem.
But I am literally doing the exact same thing from another route, and now I get an error. The application passes over the ajax function twice. The first time, I get a TypeError. If I reload the page, then the function executes correctly.
I know in the docs, it mentions having to create and object that is defined. Could somebody point me to an example of how extended controller needs to be created in order to execute a function when it is called.

I get an error: **TypeError: this.init is undefined**

Here is my route:

```
App.RegisterPickRoute = Em.Route.extend({
redirect: function() {
    var registerTestController=this.controllerFor('registerTest')
    var isRegistered=registerTestController.registerContacts();
    if(!isRegistered)
        this.transitionTo('registerTest');
    else
        alert('holla')
    }

});
```

Here is my function in my controller:

```
    registerContacts: function(){
      var isRegistered=false;
      var self=this
      self.contactsToAdd=self.get('contactList').filterProperty('isSelected', true);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: contextPath + 'user/regTest',
        data:{contactList:self.contactsToAdd},
        success: function(data) {
                isRegistered=true;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            isRegistered=false;
        },
        async: false
    });
    return isRegistered
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a syntax error. The value passed to the data attribute of the ajax call needs to be self.contactsToAdd.toArray()